# Excel's COUNTIF doesn't work

Tags: excel, countif

I'm at my wits end trying to troubleshoot COUNTIF

[image]

I see there are three instances of 11.0.6000.0162 but =COUNTIF(A1:A8559,B1) doesn't believe this.

And I evaluated the cells

=A1=B7 = TRUE

=A2=B7 = TRUE

=A5=B7 = TRUE

I have been trying to run larger figures and now I know why the numbers don't quite add up .... Thanks!

UPDATE

Here is new set of data. I thought =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$20,B1) would work, but I'm still having problems

[image]

Comment: If you use "drag and drop" maybe you have to write formula in this way: COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8559,B1)

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @DannyBland number of occurrences of values in column A, i.e.there are 2 instances of 12.5.0001.8888, and 3 instances of 11.0.6000.0162

Comment: Why there is B1 not B7 in your COUNTIF?

Comment: @user3964075 because I am dragging down the cell to bottom .... or is there another way to do COUNTIF?

Comment: @Velthune I tried this, and it doesn't work. I updated original question

Comment: Insure that you have no trailing spaces in your either your column A or Column B data. They are invisible and will make you want to throw your computer across the room.

Comment: @JNevill --- OK, I got rid of trailing spaces, and the COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8559,B1) seems to work .... need to reconfirm

Comment: If the trailing spaces are in your B column then you can just adjust the formula to account for them like `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8559,TRIM(B1))`, if they are in your A column, then you can either switch to a `=SUMPRODUCT()` formula or just quickly use `=TRIM(A1)` in a new column and copy down to clean up the values. Trailing whitespace is the devil.

Comment: Velthune JNevill combined responses helped!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming column A contains all your data, B contains the certain numbers you wish to count and C1 is where you will post the formula

`=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)`

will work if you write the number in `B1` in exactly the same format as it would be in the list.

You could then drag the formula down from `C1` as far as needed.